# Load Catalog: System no longer responding

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Whenever I run a `load catalog` I get `System no longer responding`, but obviously my server works fine, I can access all my databases across the network.

Is there any reason that I would be getting this error?  DNS seems fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a sign that the server cannot resolve its own name. It still works fine for almost everything, because almost everything on the server works by using local access (i.e., in the code, the server name is specified as "" when accessing databases).  But occasionally developers of code that runs on the server do specify the server by name when accessing databases, and this can fail if the server cannot resolve its own address. This is most often seen in agent code.

On the console of your server, which I'll call "serverX/myOrganization", enter this command:

```
trace serverX/myOrganization
```

If the trace succeeds, then I'm wrong.  If it fails to connect, then you know that your server cannot resolve its name.

You can fix this by any of several methods. One way is to make sure that the server's common name ("serverX") is resolvable in DNS. Even if there is a record in DNS for serverX, it might be the case that the DNS search path in the server's TCP/IP configuration does not include your domaain suffix, so while a ping from the server to itself via "ping serverX.myorganization.com" works, a ping via "ping serverX" fails. Another way is to just go into the server document, and on the Ports tab - Notes Network Ports subtab enter the server's full DNS name or IP address in the Net Address column of the entry for the TCP/IP port.

Comment: Wow this is some great information!  Thank you so much for taking the time to write this up.  I won't be able to test your suggestions until tomorrow at which point I'll report back on my results.